# angular async pipe, data is not filling in template

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use async pipe for Angular 2 application.

Below are different service/component code,

**Service:**

```
export class WorkoutService {

    constructor(public http: Http) { }

    getExercises() {
        return this.http.get(this.collectionsUrl + '/exercises' + this.params)
            .map((res: Response) => <Exercise[]>res.json())
            .catch(WorkoutService.handleError);
    }
}
```

**LeftNavExercisesComponent:**

```
export class LeftNavExercisesComponent implements OnInit {
    public exerciseList: Observable<Exercise[]>;

    constructor(
        public workoutService: WorkoutService,
        public workoutBuilderService: WorkoutBuilderService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.exerciseList = this.workoutService.getExercises();

        //this.exerciseList.subscribe(data =>
        //    console.log(data));
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngIf='exerciseList && exerciseList.length > 0'>
        <div *ngFor="let exercise of exerciseList|async|orderBy:'title'">
            <button class="btn btn-info col-sm-12" (click)="addExercise(exercise)">{{exercise.title}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

While I am using below code, I am able to see that API call is happening and it's gave me back the result,

```
 this.exerciseList.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

But, there is no API call in case,

```
this.exerciseList = this.workoutService.getExercises();
```

I applies 'async' pipe in html template, but it's seems this is not working.

What could be the reason? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing `orderBy` pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to use the async pipe for this code

```
<div *ngIf='exerciseList && exerciseList.length > 0'>
```

by changing it to

```
<div *ngIf='(exerciseList | async)?.length > 0'>
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear you could make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling any API then with the `Observables` you have to subscribe it to make a call. If you don't `.subscribe()` it, there won't be any call made.

In short i would say it is like *(get the data, i am listening)*. So, that is why your first example works because you subscribed it while second one doesn't.

So, ultimately you have to use something like this:

```
this.exerciseList = this.workoutService.getExercises()
                        .subscribe(excercises => excercises); // it triggers the call
```

or this way:

```
this.workoutService.getExercises()
          .subscribe(excercises => this.exerciseList = excercises); // it triggers the call
```

Comment: According to the latest documentation, which does not suck as much as it used to but still sucks, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html the `async` pipe _subscribes_ to the `Observable` directly in the template.

The workaround you mention is fine for a workaround, but it does not answer the question of how to use the `async` pipe.

Comment: @AluanHaddad o oh! how do i missed it? Yes it is there.

Comment: It seems `orderby` pipe is the issue.

Comment: @Jai, I tried by removing orderby, still the same behavior, no API call